# Accessing Model attributes in Thymleaf and Spring boot

Tags: spring, groovy, thymeleaf

I am learning to use thymeleaf templates for a project I am completing and seem to be missing something.

I am trying to create a very simple Hello type app, here is my code (note I am using groovy):

Controller:

```
@Controller
class TestController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  String homePage(@RequestParam("name") String name, ModelAndView modelAndView){
    modelAndView.addObject("name", name)
    return "home"
  }
}
```

home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p th:text="${name}" />
</body>
</html>
```

What have I missed?  I just get "Hello" and nothing else when I hit:

http://localhost:8080/app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/?name=Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have alternate option with access controller data with view name returning

```
@Controller
class TestController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String homePage(@RequestParam("name") String name,Model model){
    model.addAttribute("name", name)
    return "home"
  }
}
```

in your html file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p th:text="${name}" />
</body>
</html>
```

bind model object with parameter and now you need to set addAttribute with key and value par you can access data without using ModelAndView object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can to change ModelAndView by Model:

```
@Controller
class TestController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  String homePage(@RequestParam("name") String name, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("name", name)
    return "home"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, if I change the controller to return a ModelAndView, like so:

```
@Controller
class TestController {
  @RequestMapping("/")
  ModelAndView homePage(@RequestParam("name") String name){
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView()
    mav.addObject("name", name)
    mav.setViewName("home")
    return mav
  }
}
```

Then all is good, although the tutorials show it working like my original example - I'm quite happy to do it this way.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
class TestController {

  @GetMapping
  public String homePage(@RequestParam(name = "name") String name,Model model){
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "home";
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.